# How to use two filters on one field in PHP pure

Tags: php

I want to use two filters to apply them in one field like this:

```
<?php

$var = "hi12"; 
function addFunction($int){
    return $int + 2;
}
$myOption = array(
    "options" => "addFunction"
);
echo filter_var($var, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT | FILTER_CALLBACK,$myOption);

?>
```

I know the `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT | FILTER_CALLBACK` is not allow, but is there some equivalent way to do that ?

Comment: why not chain the calls? `$v1 = filter_var($orig, ...); $v2 = filter_var($v1, ...); $v3 = filter_var($v2, ...)`?

Comment: that is good idea, but i worked before in CodeIgniter framework which allow this way by separating the filters by (|) character, I'm asking if this allow in PHP pure to do or any equivalent way

Comment: You're asking pure PHP solution and Marc already gave it.